# how to convert this dynamic url into static url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My link is this

```
http://mr-saggu.net/Dwnld.php?id=dwl&singletrack=Jhanjhar&by=Kaka%20Bhainiawala%20Ft%20Nixon%20Minna
```

I want to change it into

```
http://mr-saggu.net/singletrack-Jhanjhar-by-Kaka-Bhainiwal-Ft-Nixon-Minna.html
```

I had written this in my `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^Dwnld-id-(.*)-singletrack-(.*)-by-(.*)\.html$ Dwnld.php?id=$1&singletrack=$2&by=$3
```

I want to convert dynamic url automatically on all songs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^singletrack-([^-]+)-by-([^.]+)\.html /Dwnld.php?id=dwl&singletrack=1$&by=$2 [L]
```

Then try it with the url you provided

```
http://mr-saggu.net/singletrack-Jhanjhar-by-Kaka-Bhainiwal-Ft-Nixon-Minna.html
```